# jquery fade in effect needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

I'am trying to figure out how to use jquery to make an image appear on the screen after a certain amount of time. I have used CSS to position the image and used display none so it can bee seen until jquery calls it in. Can anyone please help me figure out how to make that image fade in after a certain amount of time.

I have tried this.

```
$('#picture ').animate({
             width: '100px',
             height: '100px'
                }, 1000, function() {
                $(this).show('slow',{duration: 4000}
                )
        });
```

However it appears straight away. What i need is to appear over time.

Comment: `setTimeout()` and `$('img').fadeIn()`? How hard can this be?

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('#imgID').fadeIn('slow');
    }, 2000); 
});
```

Comment: This is a perfectly fine answer, and I don't mean this to sound like a personal stab if it does, but it's far better to let the OP work this (trivial) problem out themselves instead of spoonfeeding them.

Comment: No need to go crazy i asked a question i tried as u can see from code above.

Comment: @JamWaffles, I agree, it is a trivial problem. But maybe the answer will motivate him to search a little more about JQuery functions. At least i hope it will.